# Executing a single test case with django_webtest

Tags: python, django, webtest, django-webtest

In my `config/advertiser/tests/test_advertiser_web.py`:

```
from django_webtest import WebTest
...
class AdvertiserView(WebTest):
...
    def test_add_note(self):
...
```

I'd like to just run the `test_add_note` case.  Is that possible?  I can't seem to figure out how to run either the individual test case or just that file.

```
./manage.py test config.advertiser.tests.AdvertiserView
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AdvertiserView'

./manage.py test config/advertiser/tests/test_advertiser_web.py
ImportError: Start directory is not importable: 'config/advertiser/tests/test_advertiser_web.py'
```

Running the whole dir seems to work just fine:

```
./manage.py test config/advertiser/tests/
Creating test database....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add module name between `tests` and `AdvertiserView`:

```
./manage.py test config.advertiser.tests.test_advertiser_web.AdvertiserView
```

Comment: Yup, that's totally it.